# Opening the gate inside the center pit on level 4

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

On Level 4 there is a pit in the room where you get the scrolls to open the final gate. If you fall down that pit, there is a closed gate with a lever inside and some object that appears to be some sort of key,  but can't tell for sure.

I have looked around the place, but there appears to be no hidden switch. Also, toying with spells and lights did not yield results so far.

[image: Screenshot of the Gate]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fall into that cage from the 4th floor. The pit that's directly between the 4 scrolls (which usually has a teleportation field active directly on it) is the one that you need to fall down.

To be able to fall into this pit, you need to deactivate the teleportation field.

- There's a button (marked A on the map below) in a hallway outside of the scroll room which will temporarily raise two pit covers (circled on the map) in the scroll room.
- You then have to run across those before they collapse again and press a hidden switch on the wall (marked B on the map), which temporarily deactivates the teleportation field.
- You then have to run quickly to the center pit (marked C on the map) before the field reactivates.

The timing on this is pretty tight, and there's not much of a margin for wasted movement.

[image]

*Credit to [GameBanshee](http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/walkthrough/level4.php) for the level map*