# How do I open the gate in the seperate section of level 5?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening the gate inside the center pit on level 4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62797/opening-the-gate-inside-the-center-pit-on-level-4)

On level 4, with all the riddles and portals, you can drop down to level 5 on various occasions. I've explored that part completely, except for one gate that stays down. I've been painfully going over all the walls, looking for a hidden switch, but I can't find one. What's the trick here?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of your map and circle the spot with the gate you can't get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get there from level four. There's an alcove in the corridor that leads from the area with the pressure-plate puzzles (the "Trials of Thought") to the four-way intersection where you find the scrolls after each test.

In this alcove there's a hidden switch, hit it and bolt into the intersection where some of the holes will be temporarily covered with trapdoors. In the south-east corner of the room (the only corner you can reach) there's yet another hidden switch that will shut of the center (return) portal, allowing you to drop down into the locked room below.

The timing on all of this is pretty tight, so you might want to start by looking around the intersection to make sure you know where you're going. Mess it up, and you'll fall down and will have to redo the Trials of Thought to get back.

If you're ok with spoilers, the alcove is number 7 on [this map](http://images.jayisgames.com/legend-of-grimrock/log-map4.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're speaking about one of the portcullis in the part of level 5 that you can access by jumping into the pits of level 4.
There are two.

- One is "in the middle", next to the teleporter bringing you back to L4. It's a one-square room with a lever and a key. As Tzarium said, this one can be passed from L4, by opening the middle trapdoor in the final room with the four scrolls. He already described the methodology.
- The other one is in a separate section that leads to the main room. It's much bigger, but seems completely impossible to open, and one can see the chest part of the plate armor in there. This one you have to reach from L6, going up.